# Recover accidentally flushed logs file

Tags: vim, logs, tar, data-recovery

I have an Apache Tomcat running on CentOS7 server which had a file `catalina.out` of around 157MB in size. I was trying to download that file on my local system so I ran the `tar -czf` command but I accidentally ran the command in reverse direction:

`tar -czf $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out catalina.out.gz`

Which emptied the entire log file. I tried to restore the file but couldn't get success.

I saw the swap file so tried to restore the content like:

```
vim -r $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out
```

But this didn't work. Is there a way I can rollback the logs?

Answer (score 0):

The swap file created is hidden with `swp` extension, so please try using  `ls -a`  command on the location which will show the swap file.

Then `vim` the file using `.filename` and recover it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although, swap files are created when editing via tool like vim. But this happened from the `tar` command.